# RVM rails new project error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I just installed RVM and also installed ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5
(i was previously using ruby 1.9.1 with rails 3 )
But now when i try to create a new project with

```
rails new project_name
```

i get the following error

```
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/rails:14
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin/rails:19:in `load'
    from /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin/rails:19
```

I noticed that there are a couple of solutions given in stack overflow  regarding this ....something to do with editing boot.rb
But i can't find this file.
I am new to rails....any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this error before and it was more to do with the version of rubygems being too high. You can downgrade your version (1.3.6 seems to work fine) using `gem update --system 1.3.6`